# jQuery Mobile SimpleDialog: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I'm currently implementing a blankContent SimpleDialog for jQuery Mobile.
This is the html:

```
<li>
   <a href="#page1" id="searchdialog" data-theme="" data-icon="search">Search Routes
   </a>
</li>
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).delegate('#searchdialog', 'click', function() {
          $('<div>').simpledialog2({
            mode: 'blank',
            headerText: 'Route Search',
            headerClose: true,
            blankContent : 
            '<div id="content" data-role="content"><label>Enter Your Search:</label><div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup">' +
            '<label for="textinput7">Start</label><input id="start" placeholder="" value="" type="text"/></fieldset></div>'+
            '<div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup"><label for="textinput9">End</label>'+
            '<input id="end" placeholder="" value="" type="text" /></fieldset></div>'+
            '<a data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="b" href="#page6" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="left" onclick="alert($("#start").val(),$("#end").val())">Search</a>'
          })
        });
    </script>
```

I can not for the life of me figure out what is causing this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

The error only occurs when the Search Routes link is clicked, which leads me to believe it's an error in the jquery. Interestingly, if I make it

> onclick="alert()"

instead of

> onclick="alert($("#start").val(),$("#end").val())"

Then it works, but I need to have a varient of the other along the lines of:

> onclick="location.href = "/search/?start=" + $("#start").val() + "&end=" + $("#end").val()"

Thoughts on how I can accomplish this? Any quick and dirty solution will work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your line:

`'onclick="alert($("#start").val(),$("#end").val())"'`

is causing the errors. You have conflicting quotes in your onclick attribute ( and a non-string comma! )

You would be better off creating a hidden / display:none element w/this hard coded info in it then simply referring to it.

OR assigning a handler @ time that html is created (similar to your already delegated handler )

edit: Basically take this:

`'<a data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="b" href="#page6" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="left" onclick="alert($("#start").val(),$("#end").val())">Search</a>'`

and do this instead:

`'<a class="some-wonky-alert" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="b" href="#page6" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="left" >Search</a>'`

```
$('a .some-wonky-alert').on('click', function()
{
alert($("#start").val() + $("#end").val());
});
```

Season as delegated @ your convenience

edit2 : Or of course you could try to escape the quotes - but while that might work - it won't solve the bad practices being engaged in :)

Comment: how do I use escape quotes in javascript or jquery?

Comment: So I tried this: `$('a .some-wonky-alert').click(function(){
alert($("#start").val(),$("#end").val());
});` but nothing happens.

Comment: yeah that alert statement is bad too due to the comma. Not sure what the OP was trying to accomplish but a correct alert would be formatted like: 

`$('a .some-wonky-alert').click(function() { alert($("#start").val() + $("#end").val()); })`

Comment: I essentially want to do this: `$('a .some-wonky-alert').click(function(){location.href = "/search/?start=" + $("#start").val() + "&end=" + $("#end").val();});` but nothing actually happens on the page. Thoughts?

Comment: Assuming you are using a jquery version that accepts ".click()", try this : 

`$('a .some-wonky-alert').click(function()
{
window.location = "/search/?start=" + $("#start").val() + "&end=" + $("#end").val();
});`

you had an errant double quote --- note this also predicates that "start" and "end" are both available to the DOM and are unique. Also beeeeee sure that you want `.val()` and NOT  `.text()` - they perform differently

Comment: Good call. I solved it with a combination of things:
`'<a rel="close" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-theme="b" href="#page6" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="left" onClick="doSearch()">Search</a>'`
and 
`function doSearch(){location.href = "/search/?start=" + $("#start").val() + "&end=" + $("#end").val();};`
not very pretty, but it gets the job done for the project.